# writing file to static directory fails in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I want to save images to static directory in order to access them through URL. Application works **properly** in Spring Boot in Windows but when I deploy it in tomcat in Linux server nothing will be saved in this directory and no exception was thrown.
I granted all the permissions (R-W-E) to static and img directory but still does not work.

directory : src/main/resources/static/img

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/static/img/picture.jpg");
```

after running app no file named 'picture.jpg' will be exist in server

Comment: "Application works properly in Spring Boot in Windows" what does that means ? it is not possible to write in a jar during runtime... so plz clarify

Comment: @CodeScale not in Jar file... In exploded war file

Answer (score 1):

Try to save whenever you want maybe under the user directory or under `/var/html/www/images`, and give permission to the group i.e 'webserver', then add tomcat to `webserver` group

, Also try to update the configuration of tomcat for file `server.xml` and add the path to the image directory

`docBase` will be the path to the image directory,

`path` will be the path to URL when you access the webserver, in this case, will be:

`http://localhost:8080/static/test.jpg`

```
  <Host appBase="webapps"
           autoDeploy="false" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true"
           xmlNamespaceAware="false" xmlValidation="false">

    <Context docBase="/var/html/www/images" path="/static" />

  </Host>
```

[Resource](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/)